# Using custom amount in Jmeter WebDriver Sampler in graph metrics

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, jmeter-plugins

I'm using Jmeter to get daily results of website performance, specifically, the render time (which I calculate using the sum domComplete - domLoading).

I end up with the result as a new var, but I don't know how to take that amount and transfer it to a Jmeter graph to display the results. My code is below:

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get('http://www.vivastreet.co.uk/');

var completeTime = WDS.browser.executeScript('return window.performance.timing.domComplete;');
var loadingTime = WDS.browser.executeScript('return window.performance.timing.domLoading;');

var renderTime = completeTime - loadingTime;

WDS.log.info("Render time = " + renderTime);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is available only in [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5), if you're on a previous version - you will have to upgrade, moreover it is [highly recommended as per JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)

---

1. Store the result variable into JMeter Variables using [`WDS.vars`](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/#General-concepts) shorthand. Add the following line before `WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()`

   ```
   WDS.vars.put('renderTime', renderTime.toString())
   ```
2. Store the values into .jtl results file using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property and [configure JMeter HTML Reporting Dashboard to plot the custom value](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) Add the following lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=renderTime
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.title=Rendering Time
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Y_Axis=Page Rendering time
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.set_X_Axis=Over Time
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_granularity=60000
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name=renderTime
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Content_Message=Rendering Time :
   ```
3. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up